# w3c validation error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, w3c-validation

I am new in W3c validations, I am trying to fix this error but it's not happening. The error is following:

> character "&" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data.

I am using DataList Control to bind data and here is the line where the w3c validation error occurs.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDescription"  
           runat="server" 
           Text='<%#Eval("Decr") %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

In database, the `Decr` is stored and this(&) special character is also given in the description field. [w3c](http://validator.w3.org) is not validating this line.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a special charater for concat, you need to escape it: make them all `&amp;` not &.

Comment: In Database it stored as '&' , so i want to correct the validation.. is there any way to use CDATA in this code during data binding??

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Server.HtmlEncode( (string) Eval("Decr")) %>'></asp:Label>
```