# How to use delimiter text symbol (<) without getting HTML error on my webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, csv

For the paging function on my webpage I will be using the symbol < which is a delimiter. When I run an html check it give me this error:

```
Line 747, Column 318: character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data 
…quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))"><<   </a>
```

I know there has to be a way to get around this problem. Here is what my aspx code looks like:

```
 <td>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="PagerPrev" runat="server" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev"
    Text="<&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" ToolTip="Previous" />
</td>
```

If you see right after Text=" I used < and thats what the html error checker is picking up. 
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the generated source.

Comment: Check question already asked.

Using &alt; will not work. It will simply display the actual text string. not the < symbol

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689804/w3c-validation-error-in-asp-net

Comment: Here: `Line 747, Column 318: character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data 
…quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))"><<   </a>✉ 
This message may appear in several cases: 

•You tried to include the "<" character in your page: you should escape it as "&lt;"
•You used an unescaped ampersand "&": this may be valid in some contexts, but it is recommended to use "&amp;", which is always safe.
•Another possibility is that you forgot to close quotes in a previous tag.
`

Comment: It is actually funny that you have html encoded the spatial char. and not the less than. `&lt;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to encode it like you did with the non breaking spaces:

`"<"` is `"&lt;"`

The `">"` would be `"&gt;"`

Comment: Thanks Olivier. That fixed my problem. I am new to all this so this is why I could not pick it up before and asked for help. Thanks everyone for your help my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

HTML-Encode the value using `&lt;`.

If you were updating the text programmatically you could use [HttpServerUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.aspx) (exposed via the `Server` property of an ASP.NET page):

```
PagePrev.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(theValue);
```

> HTML encoding makes sure that text is displayed correctly in the
>   browser and not interpreted by the browser as HTML. For example, if a
>   text string contains a less than sign (<) or greater than sign (>),
>   the browser would interpret these characters as the opening or closing
>   bracket of an HTML tag. When the characters are HTML encoded, they are
>   converted to the strings < and >, which causes the browser to
>   display the less than sign and greater than sign correctly.

In fact, you could even do this on page with inline scripting, but largely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, if you use the “<” character in HTML content, it needs to be escaped e.g. as `&lt;`.

A different approach is to use other characters. In normal language, “<” means just “less than”. The idea of going backward or forward is perhaps better conveyed using arrow characters such as “←” e.g. as follows:

```
<style>
.arrow { font-weight: bold; font-family: Verdana; }
</style>
<a href="..." title="previous page" class="arrow">&larr;</a>
```